# normal MYSQL does not work asking for PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been trying to run my stored procedure using mysql unsuccessful for quite sometime. whenever I use the code below

```
$link_id = DbConnection::getInstance('mycon')->connectMysql();

$table_count = mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'mycon' AND table_name LIKE 'table_%' ")

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table_count)){
     $table = $row["TABLE_NAME"];
     $excute = mysql_query("dummy_2('$table')") or die(mysql_error());
     $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($excute);
     var_dump($result);
}
```

it gives an error saying

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

so when I searched the internet, it said that I need to use MYSQL PDO.. **Therefore can anyone convert my above statement to mysql pdo.. since i got no clue about PDO whatsoever**

Comment: we don't know how you initiate the MySQL connection. You got this strange `DbConnection` class, and we don't know where are your DB credentials.... You also use `mysql_fetch_array` but there's no query to do it after..... Seems like you need to paste a lot more code for us

Comment: why not try to port your code to PDO? don't be afraid to make mistakes. there's no shortage of resources with it anyway

Comment: check the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 4):

When you query something from the MySQL database the result is presented as a result set. Actually some queries might have multiple result sets associated. But there can be only one active list of results sets per connection. I.e. you, your script somehow has to close all currently active result sets before you can issue another query.
If e.g. your stored function uses multiple SELECTs the function has multiple result sets and you have to iterate/close/drop them all.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines-syntax.html:

> MySQL supports a very useful extension that enables the use of regular SELECT statements (that is, without using cursors or local variables) inside a stored procedure. The result set of such a query is simply sent directly to the client. Multiple SELECT statements generate multiple result sets, so the client must use a MySQL client library that supports multiple result sets.

The old, *deprecated* mysql_* functions do not support multiple result sets - you simply can't iterate/drop them.
The mysql**i**_* extension does: see http://docs.php.net/mysqli.next-result
And so does PDO: see http://docs.php.net/pdostatement.nextrowset.php